# wakelock not working properly

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I wrote a program where I have two services in one I collect data from accelerometer and in the second one i collect data from gyroscope.
I am using wake_lock in both.
Problem is that it is working only when I run it from android studio , then when I run it second time from phone it didn't work and stop collecting data when i lock the phone.
Can you help me where is the problem ?
THx

```
package emzet.acc2txt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "aktivita" ;
private Button btnStart, btnStop;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "ON CREATE" );

}

public void onStartClick(View view) {
    Intent serviceIntentAcc = new Intent(this, accService.class );
    startService(serviceIntentAcc);
    Intent serviceIntentGyro = new Intent(this, gyroService.class );
    startService(serviceIntentGyro);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ON START CLICK");

}

public void onStopClick(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, accService.class));
    stopService(new Intent(this, gyroService.class));
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "ON STOP CLICK" );
}



}
```

Service for accelerometer:

```
package emzet.acc2txt;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.lang.Object;

/**
 * Created by Miroslav on 2.11.2014.
 * ALL Rights reserved to eMZet
 */
public class accService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

private static final String LOG_TAG = "aktivita" ;
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
protected static SensorManager sensorManager;
// protected static SensorManager sensorManager2;
protected static Sensor accelerometer;
// protected static Sensor gyroscope;
private FileWriter writer;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON BIND");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    // accelerometer
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    // gyroscope
   // sensorManager2 = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
  //  gyroscope = sensorManager2.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Zapisujem . . . ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // register accelerometer sensor
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    // register gyroscope sensor
    //sensorManager2.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON CREATE");

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "funguj");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON DESTROY");
    wakeLock.release();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(root + "/data_acc.txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON START COMMAND");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String s = time.format(new java.util.Date());
    try {
        writer.write(s+"|"+x+"|"+y+"|"+z+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Service for gyroscope:

```
package emzet.acc2txt;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * Created by Miroslav on 2.11.2014.
 * ALL Rights reserved to eMZet
 */
public class gyroService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

private static final String LOG_TAG = "aktivita" ;
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
protected static SensorManager sensorManager;
protected static Sensor gyroscope;
private FileWriter writer;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLockGyro;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON BIND");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    // gyroscope
    gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Zapisujem . . . ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // register gyroscope sensor
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON CREATE");

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLockGyro = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "funguj");
    wakeLockGyro.acquire();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if(writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON DESTROY");
    wakeLockGyro.release();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(root + "/data_gyro.txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SERVICE - ON START COMMAND");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String s = time.format(new java.util.Date());
    try {
        writer.write(s+"|"+x+"|"+y+"|"+z+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use PARTIAL_WAKELOCK

change this:

```
wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "funguj");
```

to this:

`wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "funguj")`;

this keeps the cpu on after you pressed the lock button [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

do you have set the permission in android manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Yes I have..
I am using MIUI rom on xiaomi phone can it be the problem ?
I just discover that when I restart phone of first run it work well.

Comment: i've added something to my answer @Mirko

Comment: Thanks, this worked...
You saved me :D thx ;)

But can you tell my why full_wake_lock doesn't worked ? any idea ?

Comment: if you press the power button your phone goes to sleep with PARTIAL_WAKELOCK it will also go to sleep but it keeps the CPU on. it worked with android studio because you where connected to a power source (usb port)

Comment: Sorry,  didn't see that